# Unable to execute UI Test Cases in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

Unable to launch the iOS App on the simulator when running the XCTestCase for UI

Error: **error: attach by pid '4549' failed -- attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)**

A popup appears asking me to enter password/username of the Developers Tool group

What is this Developer Tool group ? How will i get to know the username and password and how to avoid this....

Developer Mode is already Enabled through Terminal using: **sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable**

Comment: While I can't say with 100% certainty, this will most likely work with an administrator account on your machine.